# How to fix Model.findByIdAndUpdate() return Property null

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I update my category with two parameters: title and description. If I fill both title and description => it's true. If I only fill title => category.description = null. I want if I only fill title => category.description = old description value.

How can I do this?

```
let { title, description } = updatedCategory
let category = await Category.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
    title,
    description,
    date: Date.now()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the properties conditionally

```
const { title, description } = updatedCategory

const query = {
  ...(title && { title }),
  ...(description && { description }),
  date: Date.now(),
}

const category = await Category.findByIdAndUpdate(id, query)
```

Comment: I do not know dot dot dot  in ...(title && { title }). What does it mean?

Comment: @NguyenVanTuan its called the `spread operator`, it means spread all the properties of the object to the query object. read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thank you! I have a final question. I have two models:
Category: { id, title, description, author } //author contains userId ---
User: { id, name, categories } //categories contain categoryId.

I want to check: Only author can update author's category, if you are not author, you can not update this category. How can I do it?